# Data Type issue while building notes database connections

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I fill the value of a specific notes document in a variable which has the data type VARIANT.

Reason: The value includes a backslash, letter and numbers.

Later in my code, I would like to build a database connections with this variable. Unfortunately it always fails with the following message:

> Type mismatch in method CoerceString: Unkown found, Unkown expected

My code:

```
Dim varMailFile As Variant
Dim varMailServer As Variant
Dim maildb As New NotesDatabase( "", "" )
Dim cprofile As NotesDocument

vMailFile = doc.GetItemValue( "MailFile" )
vMailServer = doc.GetItemValue( "MailServer" )

Call maildb.Open(vMailServer, vMailFile)
```

I have already try to define the varMailFile and varMailServer as String, but it stilld doesnt work. 
It makes also hard to troubleshoot, because the error message is not telling you what it found and what it expects.

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NotesDocument.GetItemValue always returns a variant, even if the item only contains one value. You need EITHER to assign the first value (Index = 0 because LotusScript is 0- based by default) to your variable or just use the first value in your call:

First possibility:

```
varMailFile = doc.GetItemValue( "MailFile" )(0)
varMailServer = doc.GetItemValue( "MailServer" )(0)
...
Call maildb.Open(varMailServer, varMailFile)
```

Second possibility

```
varMailFile = doc.GetItemValue( "MailFile" )
varMailServer = doc.GetItemValue( "MailServer" )
...
Call maildb.Open(varMailServer(0), varMailFile(0))
```